# Set minimum width for desktop layout only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a responsive design using Twitter bootstrap. Everything is going well but I cannot figure out how to set a minimum width for desktop users.

When a user is on a desktop I don't want them to be able to shrink the browser to the point where they see responsive features meant for the phone (e.g. the navbar mobile button). I would rather just have a horizontal scroll bar when the browser gets too small. How can I get this functionality without affecting the mobile layout?

Comment: do you have an example of what you mean? any other site that does this?

Comment: http://logicalvault.com/ starts scrolling when browser gets too small and shows responsive design on mobile

Answer (score 3):

You can address this with a media-query. The only problem is that you have to set a fixed `width` for this, `min-width` doesn't seem to work in this case (tested in Firefox and Chrome). If this is fine for you, you can try the following example:

```
// Should be something > 1024
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1300px) {
    body {
        width: 1300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is adding the horizontal scroll bar for desktops, but items such as the navbar are still being responsive when a desktop browser is shrunk.

Answer (score 1):

To replicate the way that logicvault.com have their site working you would need to change the Bootstrap CSS so that you only have one media query which kicks in at 480px.

Here's the media query they have set:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    // styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this functionality by using Frederic's advice:

```
// Should be something > 1024
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        min-width: 1025px;
    }
}
```

However, I also needed to adjust the bootstrap responsive files so the styles were only applied to touch devices. I ended up including Modernizr on my page and looking for the touch class.

E.g. change:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    // Styles are here
}
```

to:

```
@media (device-min-width: 768px) and (device-max-width: 979px) {

    .touch {
        // Styles go here
    }
```